# Pharo Smalltalk and mySql

Tags: mysql, database, smalltalk, pharo

I am looking for someone who knows how to interface Pharo Smalltalk and mySql.  I just want to do the basic things like "select * from names" and then read the result into Pharo.

Does anyone know anything about this?  If you have a screen video that would be super and I would buy you a beer.

Answer (score 7):

Check out [DBXTalk](https://guillep.github.io/DBXTalk/). Mariano Peck gave a presentation on it at ESUG 2011. Here's the [abstract](http://www.esug.org/wiki/pier/Conferences/2011/Schedule-And-Talks/DBXTalk) and [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HJQc22ksFCc). I'll take a Blue Moon, please ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much.  The video you gave is hard to understand.  I found the same one in a better quality: https://vimeo.com/10177955#.  Okay, so where do I send the Blue Moon?

Answer (score 4):

And what do I get? ;)
Now, really, let us know if you have any problem. There are more videos ans slides in: http://dbxtalk.smallworks.com.ar/media/.

Your scenario is pretty simple. You will need to install the MySQL client library and OpenDBX library. If it is in linux it is easy to install and compile. In windows, you can get directly the dlls. Check because all info should be in the website.

Comment: You also need to compile, but it is not as easy as in Linux. In either case, I forgot to say that you HAVE to compile in 32 bits mode (even if you are in a 64 bits box/OS). See http://dbxtalk.smallworks.com.ar/Documentation/compiling-and-installing-opendbx-native-driver/

Comment: @MarianoMartinezPeck - all the links except for the first Windows one go to the base page you have to edit there is no information there.

Answer (score -1):

> there is a package originally developed by Diego Gomez Deck and meanwhile updated in Squeaksource.
>
> Use [my metacello config script](http://lists.gforge.inria.fr/pipermail/pharo-project/2010-November/035148.html) to load ODBC support and start with ODBCConnection class.
>
> For further help you can consult the (outdated) [documentation](http://wiki.squeak.org/squeak/2480).

([Source](http://astares.blogspot.co.uk/2010/11/using-odbc-in-pharo.html))

Comment: Can you please include the link?

Comment: The entire sentence is the link.