# Smalltalk and MySQL

Tags: smalltalk

I need to do a project in Smalltalk and use relational database. I am a bit confused as I can not find much help on relational database and I need to finish the project in 20 days. Can someone please point me to a nice tutorial with examples or is n't using relational database with Smalltalk  a good idea. I need suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: [Wiki on Relational Databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database),[SO Relational Database Definition](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/relational-database/info),[Relational Database Management Systems (RBDMS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system)

Comment: maybe this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832990/pharo-smalltalk-and-mysql will be of help?

Comment: thankyou will talke a look.

Answer (score 2):

If you are developing with a web interface, then after long experimentations with my boys, we have decided that PHARO + GEMSTONE + SEASIDE is really the best way to go. Use Pharo to develop and Gemstone to deploy and *forget* the dirty and troublesome relational database part. All what is needed is to deal with objects in memory and the magically everything is persistent. Unfortunately, the  learning curve of the "setting up process" is steep and involves several actors, unless one knows before hand each of them.